# Bind Dictionary Collection to ListBox in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a dictionary collection and i need to bind it to Silverlight ListBox. I am unable to bind to ListBox using the Key value. 
Below is the Sample Code.. I get empty record
Dictionary in the code behind..

```
Dictionary<DayOfWeek, List<Book>> bookItem = new Dictionary<DayOfWeek, List<Book>>();
<ListBox x:Name="ListValues" ItemsSource="{Binding bookItem}">

                                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                     <TextBlock  Text="{Binding BookName[Tuesday]}"></TextBlock>
                             <TextBlock Text="{Binding BookDesc[Tuesday]}"></TextBlock>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    </ListBox>
```

Comment: Here is the Dictionary.. Dictionary<DayOfWeek, List<PayrollTimeTicket>>() bookItem = new Dictionary<DayOfWeek, List<PayrollTimeTicket>>();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDictionary.GetEnumerator returns a collection of `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`. So, in order to bind to your objects you need to use the properties on KeyValuePair. 
Here is an example of how you can display the data.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid>
    <!-- Display the day of week in the first column -->
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Current.Key}"/>

    <!-- Display the books in the second column -->
    <GridView Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Current.Value}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Shawn.. thanks for reply. My Book class has three properties: BookId,BookName,BookTitle. The Dictionary collections key is DayOfWeek, and value is List<Book>. Now i need to bind it to the listbox inside the Gridview. Grid view colums are Book Name, Book Title, Fri, Sat, Sun, Mon, Tue, Thu. Now the book items binding to the columns Fri .. to Thu should be based on the Key of Dictionary (Which Contains the Day to Bind). Please let me know if you understood my explanation. Thanks again for you time.

Comment: Not sure exactly how you want to display the data, but I've updated my answer to try to match your comment a little more. Hope this helps.

Comment: Shawn Here is the sample of my Grid View.. Now i Want the TextBlock's BookId and BookName to be displayed  the on the Week Columns as per the Key in the Dictionary Collection. Suppose for some of the rows the Key Contains [Tuesday] then they should be binded to the ListBox in the Tuesday column.. and if the key is [Friday] then they should be binded to the Friday column. I know it is very difficult to understand/explain.. i did my best to explain